# Ionic Angular JS distance shows twice then disappears (NaN)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, ionic-framework, nan

I have been battling with this pretty much for the whole day.

**In list1.ts:**

inside the constructor I have the following code, which gets an array of items, and places them in this.items - after that it gets the users' current position and injects a distance variable (calculated from lat/lng from firebase and lat/lng from user) into this.items

```
this.categoryId = this.navParams.get('categoryId');
  afoDatabase.list('/list', {query: {
      orderByChild: "categoryId",
      equalTo:  parseInt(this.categoryId)
  }}).subscribe(listItems => {
        this.items = listItems;


        this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition({timeout:15000}).then((resp) => {

         this.myLat = resp.coords.latitude;
         this.myLong = resp.coords.longitude;


        }).catch((error) => {
          console.log('Error getting location', error);
        });



        for (var i = 0, len = this.items.length; i < len; i++) {
            this.distance = this.calculateDistance(this.myLat, this.myLong, this.items[i].lat, this.items[i].lng);
            this.items[i]["distance"] = Math.round(this.distance);
              console.log('testing myLat', this.myLat)
              console.log('testing myLong', this.myLong)
          }

          console.log('testing inject', this.items)
        loadingPopup.dismiss().catch(() => {});
  });
```

**In list1.html:**

I show the distance using the following:

```
{{item.distance}}
```

This works fine, and the distance shows. However, if I go back a page (to the root page), and then go back to the page where I calculate the distance, I get the distance fine as well ... However, the 3rd time it just throws NaN

lat/lng shows values in console, and distance:4625 for first try

lat/lng shows values in console, and distance:4625 for second try

lat/lng shows undefined in console, and distance:NaN for the third try

If you have any idea, please let me know :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there are 2 problems here:

```
this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition({timeout:15000}).then((resp) => {
     this.myLat = resp.coords.latitude;
     this.myLong = resp.coords.longitude;
```

First this code is asynchronous, so it will be executed after your for loop, and so this.myLat and this.myLong will have the previously assigned values, that I believe will be from some initialisation or something else in your code.

Second, if you put a console.log(this.myLat, this.myLong) right after the last line of the code I have posted, I believe you will see that they are undefined. So, maybe coords doesn't have latitude / longitude properties? Try to console.log(resp.coords) to check.

Comment: Actually, when i log this.mylat and this.mylong it shows fine twice and only then it shows undefined. Exactly where you asked me to place the console log.

Comment: can you try to replace this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition by navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((resp) => {this.myLat = resp.coords.latitude; this.myLong = resp.coords.longitude;}) ?

Comment: Now on console log, when I navigate to the page I see first undefined first, and instantly i get testing myLat 52.520007 & testing myLong 13.404954. Then if i go back to root page, and go back again to the page with the list, now I get first undefined list, and instantly i get  testing myLat 52.520007 & testing myLong 13.404954 twice - instead of one time - as per the first try. On the third attempt it is just undefined (NaN). Thanks for trying to help :) Hope to get it resolved.